# Model training - cropped image of the object VS bigger image with bounding box

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, object-detection

I need to train a new model(keras+tensorflow) and I was asking myself if there is any difference between

1. Providing a bunch of images containing only the object of interest(cropped from the original image)
2. Providing bigger images with object annotations(coordinates of the bounding box and the class)

My logic tells my that most probably internally the training should be done only on the cropped part, so technically there shouldn`t be a difference.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches are you describing are commonly referred to as image classification (where a model needs to only classify the image) and [object detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection) (where a model needs to detect the location of an object in an image and classify it). Sometimes simply differentiated as "classification" and "detection". These two approaches require different techniques, and different models have been developed to handle each approach. In general, image classification is an easier problem as you may have intuited.

Which approach to use depends on your end application. If you only need to know, "does an object exist in this image" then you can use classification techniques. If you need to know "where in this image is the object" or "how many of these objects are in the image", then you should use detection techniques.

What may be non-intuitive is that object detection is not simply an extension of image classification, so if you need object detection it is best to start with object detection models instead of building an image classifier that you then extend to object detection. [This article](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/how-ssd-works/) provides some intuition on this topic.